# OkHttp 3 cliient how do I specify an alternative address for failover?

Tags: okhttp

In the docs it states that

> If your service has multiple IP addresses OkHttp will attempt
>   alternate addresses if the first connect fails

but I cant see how you specify alternate addresses when you build the request object?

Answer (score 4):

You can try to override the DNS yourself to make it happen.

```
client.setDns(new Dns() {
    @Override
    public List<InetAddress> lookup(String hostname) throws UnknownHostException {
        InetAddress ip1 = Inet4Address.getByName("127.0.0.1");
        InetAddress ip2 = Inet4Address.getByName("192.168.1.9");
        return Arrays.asList(ip1, ip2);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is to handle multiple IP addresses according to DNS. You can add more by configuring your server’s DNS settings.